# MIME decoder for Windows

Tags: windows, mime-types, encoding

Is there a (preferably command-line) MIME decoder available for Windows (like [ripMIME](http://www.pldaniels.com/ripmime/) for *nix)?

Someone sent me a MIME encoded message (this one with multiple MIME parts) that Google mail nor Outlook can decode.

PS: I don't mean a base64 decoder like [MimeDeEnCode](http://www.gaijin.at/dlmdecode.php) by [Werner Rumpeltesz](http://www.gaijin.at) (unlike the name it only decodes single base64 files, not single or multi-part MIME messages having MIME headers)

There are plenty other commandline base64 encoders I could use for that (and split the MIME file by hand into multiple base64 files first).

A good command-line base64 decoder is [base64](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64) by [John Walker](http://www.fourmilab.ch/).

Comment: MIME-encoded? As in multipart messages? Or did you mean uuencoded or quoted printable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://superuser.com/users/26316/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) got me in the right direction.

Searching for [winzip+mime](http://www.google.com/search?q=winzip+mime), I found their [knowledge base article](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/?View=entry&EntryID=103), which had a link to [UUDeview](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/) by [Frank Pilhofer](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Frank.html).

UUDeview is a tool for decoding all sorts of encoding, including MIME (and multi-part MIME too).
Even better: [UUDeview 0.5.20 for Windows (Console)](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/download/uudeview-win32.zip) contains command-line Win32 executables for decoding and encoding.

This is the command I executed to extract all attachments from the MIME file:

> `uudeview -i inputfile.mime`

Answer (score 3):

I have had success using munpack on Linux systems.  This will go through an email message saved as a text file and extract embedded images into separate files that can then be renamed as desired.

ftp://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpack-win/

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall that [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/) of all things can read and extract parts from a multipart message saved on disk.

Comment: WinZIP is not command-line, and I think it doesn't do multi-part MIME. But: your answer put me on the right track (see my own answer). +1 for getting me there.

Answer (score 2):

UUDeview didn't work for me, as there is no apparent support of the unicode .msg files my Outlook generates.

I did manage to find [MsgText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msgtext/) from the [Enter AG guys](http://www.enterag.ch/enterag/downloads/msgtext.xhtml), and it works almost exactly like ripMIME's defaults!

Answer (score 2):

After alot of trial and error I just managed to reconstruct the pdf that was mailed to me by our Ricoh Copier/scanner, split into 5 multipart mime encode emails (part 1/5 > part5/5).

Here's what I did:

1. saved all the messages as seperate .eml files (I did this in mozilla thunderbird)
2. loaded these .eml files in [UUDeview](http://www.miken.com/uud/) and decoded them into a txt file
3. used [munpack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpack-win/) to get the original attachment from the txt file. (in a dos prompt:  "munpack.exe 001.txt")

Maybe this will help someone else too